# htaccess 301 redirect to url without passing subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/word/baseball/cat/
```

To a URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/otherpage/
```

The htaccess line I'm using is:

```
redirect 301 /word/baseball/cat/ http://domain.com/otherpage/
```

But the resulting URL after the redirect ends up being:

```
http://domain.com/otherpage/baseball/cat/
```

I'd like to redirect the full URL to the new URL **without** passing the 'baseball/cat/' subdirectories, so that we hopefully end up with the URL:

```
http://domain.com/otherpage/
```

This is for a website with approximately 500 URLs like this that need to be redirected to entirely different URLs.

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: i answered without noticing the Wordpress tag.  if you are doing this for Wordpress, just [use a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/).

Comment: Thank you for the plugin recommendation. The other plugins I tested never worked, but this one did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `.htaccess` file at the top level directory, in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.  The file should at least contain these rewrite instructions:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now *all non existing* file and directory urls that come to the site will go to `index.php`.  Within `index.php` put a routing mechanism.  A very simple one would look like this:

**index.php**

```
$rurl = '';   
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
  case '/word/baseball/cat/': $rurl = '/otherpage1/'; break;
  case '/word/baseball/dog/': $rurl = '/otherpage2/'; break;
  case '/word/baseball/rat/': $rurl = '/otherpage3/'; break;
}
if (!empty($rurl)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
  header('Location: '.$rurl);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this with PHP, an alternate way **could** be the following, however it may not be too effective:

```
header('Location: http://newurl.com');
```

Also try:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "/page1"  "http://example.com/page1"  [R]
```